Binning then assembling sequencing reads
I am attempting to do something similar to the "Phylomapping"  pipeline described in this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41559-019-0914-2. I have sets of Illumina PE reads, that I want to compare against a reference genome that is annotated for CDS and CNE. So far i've used makeblastdb to create a custom db for the reference genome, and i've blasted the forward and reverse reads that I have against the reference genome with blastn and dc-megablast. I'm not sure the approach I should take to actually sort or bin the reads, and then subsequently assemble with CAP3.



Please explain what you've already tried. The figure you've displayed mentions contig assembly with CAP3 and UCLUST, and binning with NextGenMap. Have you tried using these programs? If so, what specific issues have you encountered?
